# PFFacebookUtils logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions: block: opens Facebook app instead of using system account

Tags: ios, parse-platform, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0, pffacebookutils

I've upgraded to ParseFacebookUtilsV4 and I've updated my login code as such:

```
[PFFacebookUtils logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions:FACEBOOK_READ_PERMISSIONS block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
  ...
}];
```

However, now my app switches to Facebook app for a brief moment and comes back. It uses the native Facebook app to login, while there is still a valid iOS Facebook account in Settings. How can I make `PFFacebookUtils` v4 use the system Facebook account when available, and only fall back to Facebook app when a system account is not available?

Answer (score 6):

From the Header files of ParseFacebookUtilsV4

PFFacebookUtils.h

...

> /*!  @abstract `FBSDKLoginManager` provides methods for configuring
>   login behavior, default audience  and managing Facebook Access Token.
>
> @returns An instance of `FBSDKLoginManager` that is used by
>   `PFFacebookUtils`.  */
>
> ```
> + (FBSDKLoginManager *)facebookLoginManager;
> ```

Therefore, supposedly, a declaration of "FBSDKLoginManager" is used by PFFacebookutils, let's see if this works. In fact, let's set the default to "system account", ... here's the code:

```
[[PFFacebookUtils facebookLoginManager] setLoginBehavior:FBSDKLoginBehaviorSystemAccount];

[PFFacebookUtils logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions:FACEBOOK_READ_PERMISSIONS block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
}];
```

Yes, this code compiles, this code works, just make sure you declare the login behavior before you call the login stuff, and preferably in your AppDelegate when you are initializing your code bases, Parse, Parse Facebook Utilities, etc. ..

In fact, to make sure this works for you, I just downloaded the MOST up to date version of PARSE iOS SDK and it has this same functionality. Here are your options, this is from the Facebook SDK for iOS which feeds the PFFacebookUtils:

```
@typedef FBSDKLoginBehavior enum
```

> @abstract  Passed to the \c FBSDKLoginManager to indicate how Facebook
>   Login should be attempted.
>
> @discussion  Facebook Login authorizes the application to act on
>   behalf of the user, using the user's  Facebook account. Usually a
>   Facebook Login will rely on an account maintained outside of  the
>   application, by the native Facebook application, the browser, or
>   perhaps the device  itself. This avoids the need for a user to enter
>   their username and password directly, and  provides the most secure
>   and lowest friction way for a user to authorize the application to 
>   interact with Facebook.
>
> The \c FBSDKLoginBehavior enum specifies which log in method should
>   be attempted. Most  applications will use the default, which attempts
>   a login through the Facebook app and falls  back to the browser if
>   needed.
>
> If log in cannot be completed using the specificed behavior, the
>   completion handler will  be invoked with an error in the \c
>   FBSDKErrorDomain and a code of \c FBSDKLoginUnknownErrorCode.  */

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, FBSDKLoginBehavior)
{
  /*!
   @abstract Attempts log in through the native Facebook app. If the Facebook app is
   not installed on the device, falls back to \c FBSDKLoginBehaviorBrowser. This is the
   default behavior.
   */
  FBSDKLoginBehaviorNative = 0,
  /*!
   @abstract Attempts log in through the Safari browser
   */
  FBSDKLoginBehaviorBrowser,
  /*!
   @abstract Attempts log in through the Facebook account currently signed in through Settings.
   If no Facebook account is signed in, falls back to \c FBSDKLoginBehaviorNative.
   */
  FBSDKLoginBehaviorSystemAccount,
  /*!
   @abstract Attemps log in through a modal \c UIWebView pop up

   @note This behavior is only available to certain types of apps. Please check the Facebook
   Platform Policy to verify your app meets the restrictions.
   */
  FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Opening the Facebook app is the preferred scenario for authenticating with your app according to the SDK. This behavior is defined by Facebook and their SDK and not a Parse issue really.

Unless you want to add a whole bunch of custom code to interface with iOS system account directly you'd have to live with the app opening and returning to your app. *Thats how everyone does it*... (I know, kind of lame answer)

If you want to try yourself, start looking into

```
ACAccountType *facebookAccountType = [[[ACAccountStore alloc] init] accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];
```

Comment: Uhm, it wasn't the case before updating to the latest version. Now, I'm getting random app switches to Facebook when using my app, which wasn't the case before the update.

Comment: So? Then just revert your upgrade. What do you expect to happen when an app dependency changes it's behavior? Check your code for what you are doing whenever the app switches to the Facebook app and back. My hunch is that you are requesting permissions or try to use a permission you have not requested or the like. Consider the Facebook SDK under constant development. As such, the Parse SDK needs to be updated on a regular basis. Again, that is nothing Parse's fault.

Comment: Isn't there a way to override the default behavior?

Comment: Follow the documentation for https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFFacebookUtils.html and Facebook SDK Change log https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/change-log-4.x and you will find *The SDK dialogs such as Login, Like, Share Dialogs automatically determine the best UI based on the device*.

So, no dice unless you feel up to removing your dependency to the Parse convenience methods...

Answer (score -3):

Fork Parse library from Github

Go inside it, and change whatever you want...