# Facebook SDK kicks to Safari rather than to the app (Swift)

Tags: ios, facebook, swift

I'm relatively new to programming and am coding an app that involves users registering in facebook. Whenever I press the facebook login it kicks me out to safari and kicks me back when I login. I understand the app store requires you to login without switching applications for usability, is there anyway to prevent this? When I exit the app, it seems my token is not stored and I have to log back in. I have looked through stack overflow and all the answers seemed to be in objective c and over 2 years old. I have also updated to ios 9, so this may be part of the issue. Here's my view controller code below where I create the button and add it to the vc.

```
func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result:       FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) {
    if (error == nil) {
        println("Login complete")
    } else {
        println(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}

func loginButtonDidLogOut(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {
    println("User logged out...")
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if (FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() == nil) {
        println("Not logged in...")
    } else {
        println("Logged in...")
    }

    var loginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
    loginButton.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]
    loginButton.center = self.view.center
    loginButton.delegate = self
    self.view.addSubview(loginButton)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I was facing somehow similar problem (even though with Parse integration and `FBSDKLoginManager` - check this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32195493/2609269)). The `FBSDKLoginButton` has a `loginBehaviour` property that needs to be explicitly set to `FBSDKLoginBehaviorSystemAccount` in order to prevent this wild switchovers.

Answer (score 0):

This is a security feature in iOS9.

In order to enable it, you need to add the `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` key to your `info.plist` file as an `array` type, and add Facebook's query scheme as an entry. This should be `fbauth2`

Comment: Also have a look at this page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9 under the heading `Whitelist Facebook Apps` and choose the instructions for the appropriate SDK version you're using

Comment: I'm using the the ios 9 beta sdk v4.6 and have already added this but it still opens safari. I even added the query schemes for sdk v4.5 and earlier but I still open to safari